# When i use clang -rewrite-objc main.m.there is "“The current deployment target does not support weak references”"

Tags: ios, xcode

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSMutableArray *a =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    @autoreleasepool {
        id __weak n = a;
        NSLog(@"%@",n);
    }
    return 0;
} //
```

this is my code.build sa OS X's Command line tool
[image: picture]

Answer (score 0):

Go through your project settings and check where you disable weak references. Since they have been default since 10.7 and iOS for many versions, you must have some very old and obscure project settings.

Answer (score 0):

Finally,i find the solution.Use the commond:

```
clang -x objective-c -rewrite-objc -fobjc-arc -fobjc-runtime=ios-8.0.0 -isysroot sdks yourfile.m
```

Comment: But you never showed the original clang command, so how is this helpful?

Comment: I write the original command in the title 'clang -rewrite-objc main.m'.sorry about that.